# How to typedef a struct without losing the "struct" part?

Tags: c

I want to change the name of a struct type (for instance timespec), but not lose the "struct" keyword in the process. I think it is a great way of relaying to the reader that something is a struct, so I want the new struct name to behave identically as the normal struct (having to write "struct" in declarations and function arguments)

I tried this:

```
#include <time.h>

#define TYPE_DEF_STR
#define D

#ifdef TYPE_DEF
    typedef timespec T; 
#elif defined (TYPE_DEF_STR)
    typedef struct timespec T;
#endif

#ifdef A
    struct T my_struct;
#elif defined (B)
    T my_struct;
#endif   

int main() {
#ifdef C
    struct T my_struct;
#elif defined (D)
    T my_struct;
#endif   
    
    my_struct.tv_nsec = 5;
    return 0;
}

// TYPE_DEF     + A = unknown type name ‘timespec’
// TYPE_DEF     + B = unknown type name ‘timespec’
// TYPE_DEF_STR + A = invalid use of undefined type ‘struct T’
// TYPE_DEF_STR + B = WORKS
// TYPE_DEF_STR + C = storage size of ‘my_struct’ isn’t known
// TYPE_DEF_STR + D = WORKS
```

Comment: Please note that `typedef timespec T;` will only work in C++, not C.

Comment: And `struct T my_struct;` is just plain invalid, that's not how type-names work in C. If you create a type-alias with `typedef`, that alias is a proper type-name like `int` or `struct timespec`. Doing `struct T` is like doing `struct struct timespec`.

Comment: *Why* do you want to be able to use e.g. `struct T`? What is the original and underlying problem that is supposed to solve? This is unfortunately an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) at the moment. And feels very much like it's due to a misunderstanding of something somewhere.

Comment: Don't try to create aliases just to call "Robert" "Bob". There's no reason.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correct. You have a struct like `struct some_struct {...};` and now you want to use it through another name. For instance `struct another_name var;` Is that it?

Comment: yes, exactly. I want basically an alias to some_struct, and keep having to write "struct"

Comment: To me it sounds like a bad idea but that's your decision. Anyway, I don't think `typedef`  can do it. You can do: `#define another_name some_struct` or for your code `#define T timespec` But again... I wouldn't rename "standard" names in my code. It will just make the code harder to read for others.

Comment: Please note that what you want is *very* subjective. And other programmers reading your code will just scratch their heads and wonder what's going on. It will make the code much harder to understand and maintain by others. And by "others" I also include yourself in the future when you have forgotten about this type-alias or (worse!) macro. Few teams would allow something like this pass by the code-reviews.

Comment: `typedef struct timespec struct_T;`.

Comment: "_I think it is a great way of relaying to the reader that something is a struct_` This endeavour reeks of "double think"... Seeking clarity by introducing obscurity... Experienced programmers already know the names of commonly used structs...

Comment: To have the new typename indicate the type is a structure, inclide `struct` in the name, as in `typedef struct foo struct_T;`.

Comment: This post is being discussed in reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/119tr4j/average_stackoverflow_experience/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (the names after `struct`, `union`, or `enum`) are in a different name space than ordinary identifiers (which includes type names), per C 2018 6.2.3 1. A `typedef` declares an alias in the ordinary name space, and there is no feature for declaring an alias in the tag name space, so there is no way to make one structure tag refer to another structure or its tag, aside from hammering the token with a preprocessor `#define`.

To have the new type name indicate the type is a structure, include `struct` in the name, as in `typedef struct foo struct_T;`.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to define an alias for a `struct` tag.

Yet here are some alternative approaches, each with substantial restrictions:

- you could make `struct` part of the typedef name:

  ```
  typedef struct timespec struct_T;
  ```
- you could use a preprocessor macro:

  ```
  #define T timespec
  ```

Comment: The unnamed member doesn't work.

Comment: @IanAbbott: indeed it does not. Answer amended.

Comment: Should the macro definition be `#define T timespec` so OP can use `struct T`?

Comment: @IanAbbott: yes, absolutely! Not enough sleep I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as much or as little as you like. They exist in different namespaces. That is, `struct` tags, `struct` members have unique namespaces and `typedefs` are in the ordinary namespace.

Abusing this isn't a great idea though. Example:

```
struct bird  // tag namespace
{
  DWORD bird; // member namespace
};

typedef struct bird bird; // typedef in ordinary namespace

int main (void)
{
  struct bird Bird = { .bird = 1 }; // Bird in ordinary namespace, "struct bird" is tag namespace
  bird BIRD = Bird; // BIRD in ordinary namespace, BIRD and Bird are compatible types
  if(BIRD.bird)
    puts("bird");
}
```

---

Recommendation:

`typedef struct ....` <- there, it says struct. That's how you inform the reader regarding how something is a struct. Seasoned programmers always look up the type of a variable before using it, which is nowadays easier than ever thanks to IDE shortcuts.

You might want to study the whole Windows debacle known as "Hungerian notation" where they decided to include the type as part of the typename itself. It was  massively criticized and is still used as a cautionary example of how to *not* write C code today, some 30 years later.

Answer (score -3):

Apparently, it is not possible to typedef a struct without losing the struct part. One could use preprocessor macros instead.